# Sending processed servlet data in chunks

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet which keeps reading the file and stores the search result in response and sends back to the JSP. It is taking huge time. Is there anyway that we can send the processed result like as and when it reached some size to the JSP page and whenever the user selects the next page and return the remaining result? I tried searching for this in other threads but could not find an answer.

Comment: what do you mean by "I have a Servlet which keeps reading the file and stores the search result in response and sends back to the JSP"? also put some code in here and explain more. your question is a little confusing.

Comment: So my servlet reads every line in file and searches for specific pattern if if found it sets it in the response object. The issue is the response object itself is so huge and it is taking hell lot to process and send it back to the client(jsp page)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search Servlet Pagination with JSP (or something variation of that) most of the answer you get will be with respect to paginating the results from a DB, but it shouldn't be too hard to change that to be the information coming from a file.

I'd do this for you but am on a phone now, so I help this points you in the right direction.

Edit:I would have made this a comment, not an answer (as it isn't really an answer) but my reputation isn't high enough to comment so I'm stuck with this.

Comment: That is where am stuck. Not sure how to handle if it is a file. Is there any code or snippet that you can point me? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet does a lot of work you can split it and return ready chunks to the front-end via ajax. If the job cannot be split you can consider websockets for duplex conversation with front-end.

Anyway for more detailed answer we need more info about client-server conversation and I'm not sure that JSP is good for it